# Groovy sort documentation

Tags: groovy

I am very new to Groovy and I was trying to follow some samples like

```
def list = [ [1,0], [0,1,2] ]
list = list.sort { a,b -> a[0] <=> b[0] }
assert list == [ [0,1,2], [1,0] ]
```

which works ok and is quite simple but i just can't find the sort method on

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/

If you go on List sort is not present...

I am looking in the wrong place ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sort](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28%29) [methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) are defined on the parent of the List class, which is [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html).

### Update

As you point out in your comment the Groovy JDK docs unfortunately don't show the class hierarchy. You can find out the parents/children of a particular type, by looking at the (Oracle) API docs. For example, at the top of [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) you can see that the superinterfaces of List are Collection and Iterable, and the List interface itself is implemented by AbstractList, AbstractSequentialList, ArrayList, etc

Comment: ...in javadoc at List i have All Superinterfaces:
    Collection here there isn;t and it was a little bit confusing for me..Thanks for both answers.

Answer (score 4):

Sort is defined in [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28%29).